# @RequestHeader not binding in POJO but binding only in variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am not able to bind the request header values into a POJO class. Here is an explanation:

I want to bind the value of "isKidsProfile" into "DetailCO" but it is not binding. On the other hand, it is working if I am binding it into a variable only.

// consider header value in request is: key:isKidsProfile and value:true/false

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/detail/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseDTO fetchDetailForKidsProfileUser(
        @RequestHeader DetailCO detailCO,
        @RequestHeader boolean isKidsProfile) {

        sout(detailCO.isKidsProfile);       // not bind in object
        sout(isKidsProfile);    // bind in variable

    return new ResponseDTO();
    }
```

class DetailCO {
    private boolean isKidsProfile;

```
//getters ans setters
```

}

There are more values so it will be good to bind in POJO rather than creating multiple variables. Please suggest.

Comment: Did you find solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have used for my use case where I needed to parse all Parameters. You may use [RequestHeaderMethodArgumentResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/RequestHeaderMethodArgumentResolver.html) if it's just the headers.

*Create a configuration*

```
@Configuration
public class IRSConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Autowired
private IRSArgumentResolver irsArgumentResolver;

 @Override
 public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers) {
    resolvers.add(irsArgumentResolver);
 }
}
```

---

*Create POJO class for encapsulating your data and sending to RequestHandler*

```
public class MyRequestParams {
private String first;
private String second;

public void setFirst(String first) {
    this.first = first;
}

public void setSecond(String second) {
    this.second = second;
}

public String getFirst() {
    return first;
}

public String getSecond() {
    return second;
}
}
```

---

*Create an argument resolver*

```
@Component
public final class IRSArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

@Override
public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
    return methodParameter.getParameterType().equals(MyRequestParams.class);
}

@Override
public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter, ModelAndViewContainer modelAndViewContainer,
                              NativeWebRequest nativeWebRequest, WebDataBinderFactory webDataBinderFactory) throws Exception {

    MyRequestParams requestParams = new MyRequestParams();

    requestParams.setFirst(nativeWebRequest.getParameter("x-et-participant-id"));
    requestParams.setSecond(nativeWebRequest.getHeader("Authorization"));

    return requestParams;

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to [register](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-conversion) a `Converter<String, DeailCO>`.